# How can I make this submenu 100% of height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I have this menu [here](http://jsfiddle.net/trTBU/1/) and I want the submenu to be 100% height like the top menu is.
But the submenu links should stay at the position where they are, only the black background should have 100% of height.

I tried it with `height:100%` in the `#subMenusContainer` but I think it makes it only the height of all the links in it.

Do I have to read the height of the page with JS and then calculate the margins/heights?
Or is there a simpler version with css?

For this example I use Mootools Menumatic, but in jsFiddle I use no JS, I only posted the code.

The navigation should look like [this](http://www.stoli.com/) one, when you hover over products.

Greets Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some tweeks to your CSS, is this the desired effect? - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/JPtRb/

I basically did the following:

i) made the container have a transparent `background-color`, a `width` and hid the `overflow`

```
#container{background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden; width:400px}
```

ii) gave the #nav the black `background-color` and a `height` of 100% (change this to what you want)

```
#nav{background-color:#000; height:100%;}
```

iii) changed the `top:60px` to `padding-top:60px` on `#nav`
iv) Used `borders` to get the desired effect:

`#nav ul{border-top:1000px solid #000; border-bottom:1000px solid #000; position:relative; top:-965px; }`

I think this is what you were trying to achieve...?

Comment: Well yes, but only without javascript. With JS activated it doesn't work. Thats the navigation I want to have: http://www.stoli.com/

Comment: Then its a problem with your code @madmax. Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/JPtRb/1/) where i've included jQuery, it still works.

Comment: In the fiddle only css works and when I copy the css and js code to my project it works but not with 100% height. Should it work in the fiddle ?

Comment: Which browser are you checking the fiddle in?